# mail sent succufully but not recived in inbox or spam codeingiter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am sending mail using email library in cod igniter. sometimes it works sometimes its not.It halts on any random day , Is there any permanent solution for this issue?
I have tried all these options
1. Restarted Server
2. Made Changes in system/libraries/Email.php
3. changed protocol from smtp to sendmail
4. changed smtp port to 465 to 587.
5. opend

***Send mail Function code***

```
            $this->load->library('email');

            $subject        = "Test Mail with check";
            $fromemail      ="demo@gmail.com";
            $toemail        = "demo1@gmail.com";
            $cc             = "demo2@gmail.com";

            $this->email->to($toemail);
            $this->email->cc($cc);
            $this->email->bcc($bcc);
            $this->email->from($fromemail, "$subject");
            $this->email->subject($subject);
            $this->email->message($mesg);

            $mail = $this->email->send();

            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

***Email.php Code***

```
    var     $useragent              = "CodeIgniter";
    var     $mailpath               = "/usr/sbin/sendmail"; 
    var     $protocol               = "sendmail";   
    var     $smtp_host              = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";               
    var     $smtp_user              = "somemail@gmail.com";         
    var     $smtp_pass              = "******";                
    var     $smtp_port              = "587";                
    var     $smtp_timeout           = 5;            
    var     $smtp_crypto            = "";           
    var     $wordwrap               = TRUE;         
    var     $wrapchars              = "76";        
    var     $mailtype               = "html";      
    var     $charset                = "utf-8";      
    var     $multipart              = "mixed";      
    var     $alt_message            = '';          
    var     $validate               = FALSE;       
    var     $priority               = "3";         
    var     $newline                = "\r\n";              
    var $crlf                       = "\r\n";
```

***Output***

```
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: sendmail
To: demo@gmail.com
Cc: demo1@gmail.com
From: "Test Mail with check" <somemail@gmail.com>
Return-Path: <sommail@gmail.com>
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Test_Mail_with_check?=
Reply-To: "somemail@gmail.com" <somemail@gmail.com>
X-Sender: somemail@gmail.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5797207b7169a@yoboho.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5797207b716d4"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_5797207b716d4
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

This is testing Mail


--B_ALT_5797207b716d4
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

This is testing Mail

--B_ALT_5797207b716d4--
```

Email id's are just demos . In actual code I have used right email id's.

Comment: did you installed sendmail in your web server?

Comment: yes it is installed on web server

Comment: can you please check in mail.log file, there you can find some more information regarding failures

Comment: hi,where can i get this file??